# SEO: Is it ever good to use subdomains?

Tags: seo, domains

I just built a site that I split up as follows:

```
www.MAINDOMAIN.com         --> a landing page the redirects you to one of the following pages
blog.MAINDOMAIN.com        --> a blog
restaurants.MAINDOMAIN.com --> a page that lists restaurants
shops.MAINDOMAIN.com       --> a page that lists shops
```

Problem is, won't google see his as 4 seperate domains? i.e Would I not have been better off with something like this:

```
www.MAINDOMAIN.com
www.MAINDOMAIN.com/blog
www.MAINDOMAIN.com/restaurants
www.MAINDOMAIN.com/shop
```